# Auto Archive Email for IMAP linked account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, archiving

I have a user that has 11 GB of email. It is from 12 years of use. He is accessing his email via IMAP and Outlook 2010. When synchronizing folders it takes forever. I would like to speed up the synchronizing. Is there a way to move (archive) messages older than 6 months from the email server to a pst file locally on his computer?

Background: He also accesses his email from an iPad and iPhone and needs to see everything within the past 6 months. In Outlook he has rules to automatically move messages to sub folders as soon as they come in. He still needs to be able to see how many unread messages are in those sub folders.

Comment: Yes;  Just the [`AutoArchive`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-move-or-delete-older-items-with-AutoArchive-e5ce650b-d129-49c3-898f-9cd517d79f8e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) feature built into Outlook.  It can be set to do this after 6 months.  The email will no longer exist on the server.  If the .PST is lose this means the email will be lost.  Just type `AutoArchive` into the Outlook Help feature.

Comment: The built in auto archive does not work when trying to archive from an IMAP linked account to a local pst file.  It will not move the emails. I have already tried it.

Comment: The general idea works though.  You create a .PST file then move files from the server to the local archive.  `Account Settings -> Data Files -> Add` will default to adding a new .PST file.  You can then use rules to copy/move the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook's (Auto)archiving doesn't work well with IMAP folders because archiving uses the date modified time of the emails not the date received time, which can be very different when using IMAP.

It's possible to fix this by installing a hotfix for Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010 from the link below and modifying the registry to use ArchiveIgnoreLastModifiedTime:

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/archive-outlook/autoarchiving-received-date-outlook/

> Outlook 2016:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences
>   DWORD Value: ArchiveIgnoreLastModifiedTime Value data: 1
>
> Outlook 2013:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences
>   DWORD Value: ArchiveIgnoreLastModifiedTime Value data: 1
>
> Outlook 2010:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences
>   DWORD Value: ArchiveIgnoreLastModifiedTime Value data: 1
>
> In Outlook 2007, you'll add the value to this key
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences
>   DWORD Value: ArchiveIgnoreLastModifiedTime Value data: 1